# Having trouble installing Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, boot, sd-card, software-installation

I'm currently having some trouble installing Raspbian. I am pretty new to this so im not 100% sure on what im doing. I downloaded this (https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) version onto an SD card and get this image when trying to boot it up:

[image: Image I get]

Comment: How did you install Raspbian to the SD card? It looks like the SD card was incorrectly formatted.

Comment: how many GBs does your sdcard have?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to any kind of fresh install like this best thing to do is to reformat the SD card and reinstall the OS image onto your SD card following these [instructions](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to set up your Pi page [1](https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/raspberry-pi-setting-up/2)

1. Make sure your SD card has the minimum requirements ( 8GB minimum and not exceeding 256GB if you are using Pi zero ) [Rpi documentation on SD cards](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/getting-started.html#sd-cards)
2. You need to give the required power for your pi based on its model for Pi 4 which is 5v 3A.
   It is better if you use Raspberry Pi Imager for flashing the OS onto your SD card as it. Hope it helps : )